# Скорость выполнения кода

Tags: jar, java, eclipse

Привет. Имеется код с интерфейсом с множеством методов, работающих с интернетом, с Jaco MP3Player. И дело в том, что в Eclipse все работает быстро. А если упаковать в jar, скорость работы уменьшается и достаточно сильно. Из-за чего такое может быть?

Comment: Разные JVM или разные настройки прокси или и то, и другое. Вы для начала поймите, что именно работает медленно (работа с сетью или еще чего).

Comment: Тот же компьютер, там же JVM, все одинаковое.
Вероятно, работа с плеером Jaco MP3Player происходит медленнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорость работы зависит от версии JRE

Comment: Уважаемый, я вам это в самом первом комменте написал. JVM - это несоменно часть JRE.

Comment: Я видел. Ну так, уважаемый, что ж Вы комментируете, а не отвечаете